# Local coordinate proof of the Lie derivative equals the Lie bracket

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I'm following Tu's proof of the fact that Lie derivative of a (smooth) vector field with respect to another is actually the Lie bracket of the two vector fields in his book *An Introduction to Manifolds*. I go through his proof and everything is fine but something went wrong in my argument.

To illustrate, let me recall some terminologies.

> **Definition 1.** Given a vector field $X\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ of a smooth manifold $M$, the Lie derivative of $Y\in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ with respect to $X$ is defined as follows: let $p\in M$, and let $\varphi_{t}(q)$ be a local flow around $p$; then the Lie derivative is given by
> $$
> L_{X}Y := \lim_{t\to 0} \frac{D\varphi_{-t}(Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)})-Y_{p}}{t} = \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} D\varphi_{-t}(Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)}).
> $$

To prove $L_{X} Y=[X,Y]$ by local coordinates, I worked out the local representation for $D\varphi_{-t}(Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)})$, but I received a tiny different result.

Put the smooth function $\varphi(t,q)=\varphi_{t}(q)$. Write, locally, $Y=\sum_{j} b_{j}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{j}}$. I think we should obtain
$$
D\varphi_{-t}(Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)})= \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial \varphi^{i}}{\partial x^{j}}(-t,\varphi_{t}(p))b_{j}(\varphi_{t}(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\bigg|_{p}. \tag{1}
$$
However, Tu wrote
$$
D\varphi_{-t}(Y_{\varphi_{t}(p)})= \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial \varphi^{i}}{\partial x^{j}}(-t,\color{red}{p})b_{j}(\varphi_{t}(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\bigg|_{p}, \tag{2}
$$
which I felt a bit off since the entries of the matrix for $D\varphi_{-t}$ should be evaluated at $\varphi_{t}(p)$, but Tu's result (2) seems to indicate they should be evaluated at $\color{red}{p}$ instead.

Although I don't agree Tu's result, I found an obstacle showing $L_{X} Y = [X,Y]$ if I use my result (1). The trouble is when carrying out $\frac{d}{dt}$, we obtain an additional term:
$$
\sum_{i,j,m} \frac{\partial^{2} \varphi^{i}}{\partial x^{m}\partial x^{j}}(-t,\varphi_{t}(p))a_{m}(\varphi_{t}(p)),
$$
where locally, $X=\sum_{m} a_{m} \frac{\partial }{\partial x^{m}}$ due to the chain rule. Without this term, however, we can soon finish the proof of $L_{X}Y=[X,Y]$.

So, my question is: is my result (1) actually incorrect? If both (1) and (2) are correct, how can I get from (1) to (2) by any chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $ Y_p = \sum_{i} Y^i(p) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{p}$, we have
$Y_{\varphi_t(p)} = \sum_{i} Y^i(\varphi_t(p)) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\varphi_t(p)}$. Now, the differential $D\varphi_{-t}$ applied to the basis vector $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\bigg|_{\varphi_t(p)}$ at $\varphi_t(p)$ is mapped to $\frac{\partial \varphi_{-t}(\varphi_t(p))^j}{\partial x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_{p}$, meaning
\begin{align}
D\varphi_{-t} Y_{\varphi_t(p)} = \sum_{i,j} \frac{\partial \varphi_{-t}(\varphi_t(p))^j}{\partial x_i}Y^i(\varphi_t(p))\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_{p}.
\end{align}
So you are definitely right, in that Tu's equation is not correct.
But from your formula, we can prove now prove the desired Theorem:
Applying $\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0}$, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \big(D\varphi_{-t} Y_{\varphi_t(p)} \big) &= \sum_{i,j}  \bigg(\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \bigg(\frac{\partial \varphi(-t,\varphi_t(p))^j}{\partial x_i} \bigg)  Y^i(p) +
\frac{\partial \varphi(0,p)^j}{\partial x_i}  \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} Y^i(\varphi_t(p)) \bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p} 
\\
&= \sum_{i,j}  \bigg(
-1\cdot\frac{\partial \varphi(0,p)^j}{\partial t\,\partial x_i}  Y^i(p)+
\sum_k
\varphi(0,p)^k\frac{\partial \varphi(0,p)^j}{\partial x_k\partial x_i} Y^i(p)
+
\frac{\partial \varphi(0,p)^j}{\partial x_i}  \frac{\partial\varphi(0,p)^k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial Y^i(p)}{\partial x^k} \bigg)  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p} \\
\end{align}
Since $\varphi_0(x)=x$, we have $\frac{\partial \varphi(0,p)^j}{\partial x_i} = \delta^j_i$  and the second spatial derivatives vanish at $t=0$. Furthermore, we have $\frac{\partial \varphi(x,0)}{\partial t} = X_x$. Plugging that in, we find
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \big(D\varphi_{-t} Y_{\varphi_t(p)} \big) 
&= \sum_{i,j}  \bigg(
-1\cdot\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_i}  Y^i(p)
+\sum_k
\delta^j_i  \frac{\partial\varphi(0,p)^k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial Y^i(p)}{\partial x^k} \bigg)  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p} \\
&=\sum_{i,j}  \bigg(
-1\cdot\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_i}  Y^i(p)+\sum_k
 \frac{\partial\varphi(0,p)^k}{\partial t}\frac{\partial Y^j(p)}{\partial x^k} \bigg)  \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p} \\
&=\sum_{i,j}  \bigg(
-1\cdot\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_i}  Y^i(p) \bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p} + \sum_{j,k} \bigg(
 X^k\frac{\partial Y^j(p)}{\partial x^k}    \bigg) \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\bigg|_{p}\\
&=\sum_{i,j}  \bigg(
X^k\frac{\partial Y^j(p)}{\partial x^k} -\frac{\partial X^j}{\partial x_i}  Y^i(p) 
    \bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} \bigg|_{p}\\
&=[X,Y]_p.\\
\end{align}
This finishes the proof.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! You just pointed out what I missed!